# What to do for an answer I gave that I can't update?

Tags: support, editing, answers

Please take a look at [my answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/73779/25656) to [gnome-terminal tabs are very dark, difficult to tell which tab is in use](https://askubuntu.com/q/46182/25656). I'm now using Lubuntu and don't use GNOME terminal or gedit. For this reason, I won't be in a position to update  my answer if the need arises.

What should be done?

Comment: welcome to the wide, wide world of community editing. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Leave it. If someone comments that it doesn't work, etc they you can consider removing it, or you can just leave it. Either someone else will edit your answer or provide a more current answer.

Answer (score 3):

Other people can improve it as necessary.

As Marco Ceppi says, you can remove it if it stops being useful... but usually, it can be edited (by someone) to keep it helpful.

For an answer that had to be updated *very frequently*, it would make sense to make it community wiki, so any user with 100 reputation or more could edit it without their edits having to be approved. (It would become CW by itself though, after 10 or so edits.)